# サーバーのプライベートip127.0.0.1がローカルマシンの127.0.0.1を指すことがある件

Tags: network, nginx, サーバー管理

サーバーで`node.js`のアプリを動かすと度々このような自体に見舞われます。
フレームワークは`nuxt.js`です。

そもそも`127.0.0.1`というのはマシン内部のプライベートなipであり、グローバルipとは違うはずだと思うのですが

例えばローカルマシンの`127.0.0.1:4000`でAPIサーバーを起動させている間
サーバーにデプロイしているアプリ`127.0.0.1:3000`から`127.0.0.1:4000`へリクエストすると
ローカルマシン上で稼働させている`127.0.0.1:4000`のアプリにリクエストが飛んできます。

正直、どういう理屈なのか全くわかりません。
そもそも、サーバー内では`127.0.0.1:3000`はnginxで公開しています。
`127.0.0.1:4000`は公開していません。
リバースプロキシをやって公開しているのは`127.0.0.1:3000`だけです。

何がやりたいというと`127.0.0.1:4000`のAPIは誰彼構わず叩かれたくないので公開したくないのです。
ただし`127.0.0.1:3000`のアプリからだけは利用したい

サーバー内のlocalhostを
同サーバーから公開されているアプリのみ利用可能とする方法は無いのでしょうか？

元々フロントエンドエンジニアなのでサーバーのその辺の事情が分かっていません。

安全性から言ったら当然、公開するサーバー、非公開でlocalhostとしてだけ動かすサーバーという
構成でアプリは運用できるものと思っていたのですが
違うのでしょうか？

`127.0.0.1:3000`のアプリで
`127.0.0.1:4000`のAPIを叩かせようと思ったら
やはり`127.0.0.1:4000`のAPIも公開した上で、nginxの設定やらで同サーバーからのみ利用可能な設定にしてやらなければならないのでしょうか？

もはやlocalhostがなぜこのような仕組みになっているのかわけが分からないです。

詳しい方ご教示頂けないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「127.0.0.1:4000」へのアクセスを実施しているのは「サーバー側(Node.js)」ですか？それとも「クライアント側(ブラウザ)」ですか？もしくは「どちらなのかわからない」ですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
graphqlサーバーに対してapolloからclientConfigsのhttpEndpointの設定に
http://127.0.0.1:4000を指定しています。
なのでクライアント側ですね。
ブラウザのネットワークでもhttp://127.0.0.1:4000と表示されています。
しかしながらapolloのドキュメントはどこを見てもhttp://127.0.0.1:4000
などhttp://127.0.0.1となっています。
サーバーでの運用を想定していないとは思えないのですが
ブラウザ側からhttp://127.0.0.1:4000へリクエストが飛べば当然、ローカルで稼働中のhttp://127.0.0.1:4000アプリへリクエスト飛びますよね；；

一体どうすれば良いのやらという状態です。
現状想像できるのはhttp://127.0.0.1:4000のapi用にもう一つドメインを取得してapiも公開状態にするしか無いのかと思っている状態です。
ドメイン2つ用意しないといけないとなると
graphqlの利用というのは苦しいものがありそうですね。

Comment: サーバーサイド（Nuxt.js で作成、nginx で公開）から Apollo サーバーに GraphQL クエリしたいのにブラウザから HTTPリクエストが飛んでいる、ということでしょうか？ Nuxt.js も Apollo (Server?) も詳しくないですが、設定だかプログラムだかを適切に変更するとサーバーサイドで 127.0.0.1:4000 へリクエストされるんですかねえ。 
いずれにせよ実際の設定、プログラムコード、デプロイや実行の様子のスクリーンショットとかを本文に追記すると答えが得られやすくなると思います。

Comment: コードの情報が足りないので回答するにはかなり難しいのでスクリーンショットやコードを追加して情報を詳しく教えてください。

Comment: 詳細な回答を得るために書いてほしい事。「公開するサーバー」の 外向けのIPアドレス。「ローカルマシンの127.0.0.1:4000」が動いているローカルマシンの外向けのIPアドレス。 それぞれは LAN ケーブルで接続されていますか? 仮想マシンの親と子の関係だったりしますか？  「誰彼構わず叩かれたくない」と思っている そのマシンの サーバーから見たIPアドレス。  これが ちゃんと整理して説明できたら、ルーティング設定、ファイアーウォール設定のアドバイスができると思います。  基本は 外のマシンに向けてポートを開ける、開けないの設定。 このポートでアクセスしてきたらこのアプリに 転送する設定、呼び出し元のIPアドレスによって 処理を制限する設定を組み合わせて 設定します。 あとは どんな アプリ、機材を利用するか、費用や設定、安定性運用性の問題です。

Comment: IPV4において127.0.0.1はローカルループバックアドレスという自分自身を指す特別なアドレスです。通常TCP/IPを使うとき機器には他のアドレスを割り当てます。リモートデスクトップでアプリを運用しているとかでなければ`誰彼構わず`はたたけません。もし127.0.0.1でなにかが公開できるような運用であれば、運用自体をみなおしてたほうがよいとおもいます。